# Reading data from Excel sheets and building SQL statements, writing to output file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel book with a couple of sheets. Each sheet has two columns with `PersonID` and `LegacyID`. We are basically trying to update some records in the database based on `personid`. This is relatively easy to do TSQL and I might even be able to get it done pretty quick in powershell but since I have been trying to learn Python, I thought I would try this in Python. I used `xlrd` module and I was able to print update statements. below is my code:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\Scripts\UpdateID01.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

myList = []
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
   myList.append(sheet.row_values(i))


outFile = open('D:\Scripts\update.txt', 'wb')

for i in myList:
    outFile.write("\nUPDATE PERSON SET LegacyID = " + "'" + str(i[1]) + "'" + " WHERE personid = " + "'" + str(i[0])
                  + "'")
```

Two problems - when I read the output file, I see the `LegacyID` printed as float. How do I get rid of `.0` at the end of each id? Second problem, python doesn't print each update statement in a new line in the output text file. How to I format it?

**Edit**: Please ignore the format issue. It did print in new lines when I opened the output file in Notepad++. The float issue still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you turn the LegacyID into ints ?

i[1] = int(i[1])

outFile.write("\nUPDATE PERSON SET LegacyID = " + "'" + str(i[1]) + "'" + " WHERE personid = " + "'" + str(i[0])
                  + "'")

Comment: Thanks, chris. When I first tried the int conversion, it said `invalid literal for int() with base 10: LegacyID`. I realized that I need to skip the first row which has column names and adjusted `range(1, sheet.nrows)` and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
# use 'a' if you want to append in your text file
outFile = open(r'D:\Scripts\update.txt', 'a')

for i in myList:
    outFile.write("\nUPDATE PERSON SET LegacyID = '%s' WHERE personid = '%s'" %( int(i[1]), str(i[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning Python (which is very laudable!) you should start reading about [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) in the Python docs. This is the best place to start whenever you have a question light this.

Hint: You may want to convert the float items to integers using `int()`.